# Unix: Directory listing including last modified time

Tags: unix

I have a directory tree with lots of branches and trees. At the top node, however, there are only five directories, let's say A-E. Within the directory tree, files are being updated at random.

I'd like to be able to get a listing of the directories (that is, like an [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls)) with a last modified file time which includes *all* sub directories and files within that directory. So I will end up with something like this:

A 12th June 08:00
B 13th June 08:00
C 14th June 08:00
D 15th June 08:00
E 16th June 08:00

I've tried variants on `ls -t`, but that does not seem to take sub-directories into account.

There's also something like this `find . -type f | xargs ls -tr`, but I can't see a way of getting the output I want using this (note: I'm very limited in my Unix knowledge, as you can probably tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in A B C D E
do
    file=$dir
    while [[ -n $file ]]
    do
        prev=$file
        file=$(find $dir -newer $file -type f -print -quit)
    done
    mod=$(stat --format=%Y "$prev")
    echo "$dir $(date --date=@$mod '+%d %b %T')"
done
```

Comment: If you are going to assume *stat* (utterly reasonable), you can avoid the (potential) O(n^2) performance hit: `mod="$(find "$dir" -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format=%Y | sort -rn | head -1)"`

Comment: Or a solid O(n): `mod=$(max=0; find "$1" -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format=%Y | while read -r dt; do test $dt -gt $max && max=$dt && echo $max; done | tail -1)`

Comment: @Chris: Yes, yours is **much** faster. You should post it as an answer. However, you should know that the `head -1` style is deprecated (and on my system `tail -1` flat out refuses). It should be `head -n 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ls -clRt`. It is recursive, and sorts by last modified time.

Comment: Does not answer the question -- the poster was not asking for a recursive list of directories and their contents but rather a flat list of specific items, each alongside a stat (last modified file time) that has been obtained by recursive traversal.